# Splitting values into two columns powershell csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script that creates a csv file and neatly separates all user input. I need the remaining output to be split across the two headers and I'm struggling to find out how. Tried lots of different code but had no luck.

```
$Devices = read-host -Prompt "Enter Full Device Name" | out-file 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Force
$Find = ", "
$Replace = "`n"
$Arrange = (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv') -replace "$Find","$Replace" | Set-Content 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Force
$CSV = import-csv 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Header "Firstname","Lastname" 
$CSV | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' 
$import = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv'
```

This is the output I currently have in the CSV:
[image: Output]

This is the output I am after:
[image: Final Output]

Could almost do with a foreach loop as the first and last names are likely to change as these are inputted using a variable

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Export-Csv` exports 1 column *per distinct property* of the input - so to get 2 columns, you need to pipe an object with 2 properties to `Export-Csv`.

```
# read device names, split into individual strings
$devices = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Full Device Name(s)"
$devices = $devices -split ',\s*' |ForEach-Object Trim

# now create one object per device name
$records = $devices |ForEach-Object {
  # start by splitting the string into 2 on the first `-`
  $FirstName,$LastName = $_ -split '-',2

  # now create the object
  [pscustomobject]@{
    FirstName = $FirstName
    LastName = $LastName
  }
}

# ... and finally, export to CSV
$records |Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If you want to retain the `-` as part of the `FirstName` value, change this line:

```
$FirstName,$LastName = $_ -split '-',2
```

to:

```
$FirstName,$LastName = $_ -split '(?<=-)',2
```

Comment: Upvoted, with a quibble.  Your code eliminates the hyphen when you split, right?

Comment: @WalterMitty It does indeed, I've updated the answer to show how to retain it (if necessary) now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Since I don't know what your input file looks like there might be some redundant steps in there. Feel free to modify the code to remove any redundant lines if you feel like.

```
$Devices = read-host -Prompt "Enter Full Device Name" | out-file 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Force
$Find = ", "
$Replace = "`n"
$Arrange = (Get-Content 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv') -replace "$Find","$Replace" | Set-Content 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Force
$CSV = import-csv 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Header "Firstname","Lastname" 
$X = $CSV | select -Skip 1 
$y = $x -replace '-','-,' # this adds a comma so that the values are in different columns
$y | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv'
$import = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Devices.csv' -Header  "Firstname","Lastname"
```